# SDL renders blackscreen c++

Tags: c++, sdl

I follow the tutorial but rendering black screen.Cant set a bg color.

[image]

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SDL_Window * window = nullptr;

    SDL_Surface * window_surface = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface * image_surface = nullptr;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("test_environment", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;

    image_surface = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
    window_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    bool is_running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    while (is_running) {

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                is_running = false;
            }
        }
       
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 12, 22, 255);
        SDL_Rect rect{0,0,600,400};
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_Delay(16);
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image_surface);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: getting this error on debug. mode :flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35 maybe that matters

Comment: removed that two lines and worked :   image_surface = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
    window_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

Comment: Have you tried checking [`SDL_GetError()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError)? I wonder if it might be an OS thing, with some attributes not being set correctly. Because running your code on Windows, it works as expected.

Comment: it said: Couldn't open image.bmpRenderer already associated with window

Comment: Why are you faffing about with `SDL_GetWindowSurface()` if you're going to be using a Renderer?  Per [the docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface): "You may not combine this with 3D **or the rendering API** on this window. "

Comment: yeah i only tried tutorial on the page, which showd nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you clear your renderer before you set your draw colour. Every time in the loop add `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255)`;
`SDL_RenderClear(renderer);`